# i have a problem filtering items from my API to display in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-hooks, redux-toolkit

so this is my code, I'm sure all the data from the Redux slice is correct and changing on time, but the filtered products does not display onChange and remains static, except for the sort method. Here is all the JS file and thank you in advance.

```
import { FilterAlt } from '@mui/icons-material';
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import Card from './Card';
import Filter from './Filter';
import productsData from '../../../data/productsData.json';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';

export default function Shop() {
  const [filterOpened, setFilterOpened] = useState(false);
  const filterIconRef = useRef('');
  const [initialIconRender, setInitialIconRender] = useState(true);
  const [selectedCategories, setSelectedCategories] = useState(['All']);
  const [searchInput, setSearchInput] = useState('');
  const [priceR, setPriceR] = useState({
    enabled: false,
    min: 0,
    max: 9999999
  });
  const [sortingMethod, setSortingMethod] = useState('BY_ID');

  const filterCategories = useSelector(
    state => state.Products.filterProducts.byCategory.categories
  );
  const filterSearchInput = useSelector(
    state => state.Products.filterProducts.bySearchInput
  );
  const filterPriceRange = useSelector(
    state => state.Products.filterProducts.priceRange
  );
  const itemsSortedBy = useSelector(
    state => state.Products.filterProducts.sorted
  );

  function toggleFilter() {
    setFilterOpened(prevFilterOpened => {
      if (!prevFilterOpened) {
        document.body.style.overflowY = 'hidden';
        filterIconRef.current.classList.replace(
          'translate-x-0',
          'filter-icon-on'
        );
      } else {
        document.body.style.overflowY = 'auto';
        filterIconRef.current.classList.replace(
          'filter-icon-on',
          'translate-x-0'
        );
      }
      return !prevFilterOpened;
    });
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    setSelectedCategories(filterCategories);
    setSearchInput(filterSearchInput.input);
    setPriceR(filterPriceRange);
    setSortingMethod(itemsSortedBy);
  }, [
    filterCategories,
    filterSearchInput.input,
    filterPriceRange,
    itemsSortedBy
  ]);

  return (
    <div className="w-full h-auto min-h-screen bg-primary-gray pt-20 bg-shop">
      <div className="md:flex">
        <Filter isOpened={filterOpened} />
        <div className="w-[95%] h-auto p-4  mx-auto">
          <div
            className="flex cursor-pointer mb-5 md:hidden translate-x-0 transition-all duration-300"
            onClick={toggleFilter}
            ref={filterIconRef}
          >
            <FilterAlt></FilterAlt>
            <h1>Filter</h1>
          </div>
          <div className="items w-full h-auto relative flex justify-start flex-wrap">
            {productsData.products
              .filter(e => {
                return (
                  ((selectedCategories.includes(e.category) ||
                    selectedCategories.includes('All')) &&
                    (e.name.toLowerCase().includes(filterSearchInput.input.toLowerCase()) ||
                      !filterSearchInput.enabled) &&
                    e.price > priceR.min &&
                    e.price < priceR.max) ||
                  !priceR.enabled
                );
              })
              .sort((a, b) => {
                switch (sortingMethod) {
                  case 'BY_ALPHABET':
                    return a.name.localeCompare(b.name);
                  case 'BY_HIGHEST_PRICE':
                    return b.price - a.price;
                  case 'BY_LOWEST_PRICE':
                    return a.price - b.price;
                  case 'BY_RATING':
                    return b.rating - a.rating;
                  case 'BY_ID':
                    return a.id - b.id;
                  default:
                    return;
                }
              })
              .map(e => {
                return (
                  <Card
                    primaryPicture={e?.pictures?.[0]}
                    key={e?.id}
                    name={e?.name}
                    price={e?.price}
                  />
                );
              })}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I've tested all the data including the **useSelector** and **useState** data and the filter component onChange and the other effects, so I am pretty sure that the problem is only on the **filter** function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the filtered products are not changing as per the selected categories, search input, and price range in real-time. The sorting method works correctly, but the filtered products remain static.
try this

```
import { FilterAlt } from '@mui/icons-material';
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Card from './Card';
import Filter from './Filter';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';

export default function Shop() {
  const [filterOpened, setFilterOpened] = useState(false);

  const filterCategories = useSelector(
    state => state.Products.filterProducts.byCategory.categories
  );
  const filterSearchInput = useSelector(
    state => state.Products.filterProducts.bySearchInput
  );
  const filterPriceRange = useSelector(
    state => state.Products.filterProducts.priceRange
  );
  const itemsSortedBy = useSelector(
    state => state.Products.filterProducts.sorted
  );

  const productsData = useSelector(state => state.Products.products);

  const toggleFilter = () => {
    setFilterOpened(prevFilterOpened => !prevFilterOpened);
  };

  return (
    <div className="w-full h-auto min-h-screen bg-primary-gray pt-20 bg-shop">
      <div className="md:flex">
        <Filter isOpened={filterOpened} />
        <div className="w-[95%] h-auto p-4  mx-auto">
          <div
            className="flex cursor-pointer mb-5 md:hidden translate-x-0 transition-all duration-300"
            onClick={toggleFilter}
          >
            <FilterAlt />
            <h1>Filter</h1>
          </div>
          <div className="items w-full h-auto relative flex justify-start flex-wrap">
            {productsData
              .filter(product => {
                const selectedCategoriesIncludeAll =
                  filterCategories.includes('All');
                const isInSelectedCategories = selectedCategoriesIncludeAll
                  ? true
                  : filterCategories.includes(product.category);
                const isInSearch =
                  product.name
                    .toLowerCase()
                    .includes(filterSearchInput.input.toLowerCase()) ||
                  !filterSearchInput.enabled;
                const isInPriceRange =
                  !filterPriceRange.enabled ||
                  (product.price > filterPriceRange.min &&
                    product.price < filterPriceRange.max);

                return isInSelectedCategories && isInSearch && isInPriceRange;
              })
              .sort((a, b) => {
                switch (itemsSortedBy) {
                  case 'BY_ALPHABET':
                    return a.name.localeCompare(b.name);
                  case 'BY_HIGHEST_PRICE':
                    return b.price - a.price;
                  case 'BY_LOWEST_PRICE':
                    return a.price - b.price;
                  case 'BY_RATING':
                    return b.rating - a.rating;
                  case 'BY_ID':
                    return a.id - b.id;
                  default:
                    return 0;
                }
              })
              .map(product => (
                <Card
                  primaryPicture={product.pictures?.[0]}
                  key={product.id}
                  name={product.name}
                  price={product.price}
                />
              ))}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```